# Structuremap type mapping

Tags: c#, structuremap

I currently have:

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For<IService>().Use<Service>().Singleton();
}
```

This replaces all instances of new IService() with new Service();

I also have:

```
var T = typeof(IService);
```

How do I inject Service there?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to initialize an attribute with dynamic parameters.     [Log(type = typeof(IService))]

Comment: And why do you want to tightly couple that to an implementation instead of using an interface?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using a dependency injection library in the first place?

Comment: I want to inject Service (implementation) where it says IService (interface).

Comment: Maybe we're both missing something?  I don't see exactly what the problem is, StructureMap should be providing an instance of `Service` any time an instance of `IService` is requested from it.  And throughout the rest of the domain the only type information needed is just `IService`.  It's not clear to me what's broken here.

Comment: The problem is T becomes type IService instead of Service.

Comment: Right, but why is that a problem?  Any instance of `Service` is of type `IService`.  If that `typeof()` code is outside of the dependency implementation then it should never know about `Service`, only about `IService`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67717/discussion-between-user3233089-and-david).